# How to update Database User Password in Moss 2007 after changing it?

Tags: sharepoint-2007

Being concerned about Security, I change my DataBase password over a period of time. So once this change happens, I also should update the same in all relative applications, and I am stuck with doing that on MOSS 2007.

How can we update the DataBase User password on a MOSS 2007?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what your looking for:

http://blogs.msdn.com/joelo/archive/2006/08/22/712945.aspx

Comment: I should add that you shouldn't manually modify the IIS properties associated with the SharePoint farm.  In the best case SharePoint will just undo/ignore your change, in the worst case things blow up.  Using stsadm and Central Admin as suggested in the article is the correct approach.

Comment: Yes Mayo is right. you have no need to use IIS and sharepoint

Comment: Thank you gentlemen. Let me see how this helps.

Comment: I have been changing the Application Pool pwd from IIS. Some times the it automtically stops running and I dont see any issues in the 
Event viewer except for Audit failure. Is this the right way or should we be doing this from STSADM?